How to intercept the sleep button press and cancel its action?
I use this code to intercept the keyboard Sleep button down and up action:
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardMsgProc, hInstance, NULL);

//...

LRESULT WINAPI KeyboardMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbhs = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);

    if(kbhs->vkCode == VK_SLEEP)
    {
    OutputDebugStringA("VK_SLEEP catched\r\n");
    return 1;//deny button action
    }

return CallNextHookEx(kb_hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

The button press is intercepted (this is logged). But the computer still goes into sleep mode.
So how to intercept the sleep button press and cancel its action?

The WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook enables you to monitor keyboard input events about to be posted in a thread input queue. It can't cancel the sleep. return 1;//deny button action - this does not do what is commented. It stops passing the message to other hooks: return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.

You question is XY-problem. Your task is: how to prevent Windows from sleep. You are asking how to intercept the sleep button and cancel its action. Google for the task and you will find a few answers on SO.

@273K so why does it work for all other keyboard buttons and not for VK_SLEEP? The event is caught, but only after entering sleep mode.

Do you want to stop sleep? Or do you have to solve it the way you've decided to solve it, even if it doesn't solve the problem?

Similar to Ctrl+Alt+Del, Power Management including Sleeping is a reserved action by the OS. You can't block it via a keyboard hook. The correct way to block sleeping is to use SetThreadExecutionState() instead.

@RemyLebeau I'm using this code: SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED); and it returns ES_CONTINUOUS (previous state). But when I press Sleep butoon on my keyboard the computer goes to sleep anyway. What's wrong? Win7 x64.

Try including ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED

@RemyLebeau Done but it didn't help. Does it work for you? I also used PowerCreateRequest() / PowerSetRequest() functions, but this also does not prevent the PC from going to sleep after pressing the Sleep keyboard button. This is weird. Is there any other way?

@DavidHeffernan yes, I want the PC not to go into sleep mode after pressing the keyboard sleep button or when pressing the Start menu -> Sleep. Any ideas?

I suggest that you rewrite the question accordingly to ask about your problem rather than the solution that doesn't work

@DavidHeffernan My question is stated quite clearly in the comments above.
But you haven't written a single useful message here.
If you don't know the solution or don't want to answer or you're just increasing your message count here,or you have another reason, then please ignore this thread. Thanks!

I'm offering advice on how you can get help. Asking needs to be done in the question and not in comments. Use the edit button to edit the question. You have had no answers. That's because you asked the wrong question.

Unfortunately, no one here has given an answer to my question. But I tried many different functions and methods etc. I also found out that the low-level keyboard hook catches message VK_SLEEP after the PC starts to go into sleep mode. So there's no point in processing it.
For example, the SetThreadExecutionState() function noticed by RemyLebeau will prevent the PC from going into sleep mode only when the internal system timer expires.
And processing WM_POWERBROADCAST and WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages also didn't cancel the PC’s entering to sleep mode after the keyboard Sleep button pressed.
So the solution to my question is to use the power management functions: PowerGetActiveScheme(), PowerWriteACValueIndex(), PowerSetActiveScheme():
//init - receive the original power scheme, preserve it and duplicate it for further usage

pDuplicateActivePowerScheme = NULL;
pCurrentActivePowerScheme = NULL;

if(PowerGetActiveScheme(NULL, &pCurrentActivePowerScheme) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
return;

if(PowerDuplicateScheme(NULL, pCurrentActivePowerScheme, &pDuplicateActivePowerScheme) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
return;

Cancel the keyboard Sleep button action:
if(PowerWriteACValueIndex(NULL, pDuplicateActivePowerScheme, &GUID_SLEEPBUTTON_ACTION, &PowerSettingGuid, 0) != ERROR_SUCCESS)//0 - prevent action
return false;

if(PowerSetActiveScheme(NULL, pDuplicateActivePowerScheme) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
return false;

When the action is no longer required to be cancelled:
//cleanup and restore the original power scheme

if(pCurrentActivePowerScheme != NULL)
{
if(PowerSetActiveScheme(NULL, pCurrentActivePowerScheme) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
if(pDuplicateActivePowerScheme != NULL)
{
PowerDeleteScheme(NULL, pDuplicateActivePowerScheme);
LocalFree(pDuplicateActivePowerScheme);
pDuplicateActivePowerScheme = NULL;
}
}

LocalFree(pCurrentActivePowerScheme);
pCurrentActivePowerScheme = NULL;
}

This can also be used to cancel the action of the keyboard Power button press. It works on Vista and higher (I haven't tested it on XP). For convenience, I wrote my own class to disable the actions of the power buttons. Keep in mind that this code does not prevent Start menu -> Shut down / Sleep action (I didn't ask that). Thanks to PJ Arends for his article, which helped me to solve my question.
